# Is _Thread_local independent from __STDC_NO_THREADS__?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

It seems that currently `_Thread_local` is independent from `__STDC_NO_THREADS__`.

Consequence: even if an implementation defines `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` to 1, then it still needs to support (at least to accept) `_Thread_local`. I guess that it is a defect. Is that correct?

---

UPD: Relevant proposal for C2x: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2291.htm.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a defect to me, more likely an intentional choice for compatibility.  Think about implementing a function like `rand()`.  It doesn't particularly need threads, but if the program is multithreaded, then you want its internal state to be thread-local.  If `_Thread_local` is supported universally then you can save yourself some `#ifdef`s: just declare the variable as `_Thread_local`, and understand that on an implementation without threads, the `_Thread_local` just won't do anything.

Comment: @NateEldredge Does "implementation without threads" == "implementation supporting a single thread"? From "Under a hosted implementation, a program can have more than one thread of execution" and "Under a freestanding implementation, it is implementation-defined whether a program can have more than one thread of execution" (C11, 5.1.2.4, 1) it follows that a program has _at least one_ thread of execution. Hence, indeed the `_Thread_local` "just won't do anything".

Comment: By "implementation without threads" I would include any freestanding implementation for which a program can't have more than one thread of execution.  I would also include any implementation, hosted or freestanding, in which a program "can" have more than one thread of execution as per 5.1.2.4, but which does not actually provide any mechanism to start more than one thread.  That would include most implementations that define `__STDC_NO_THREADS__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct but it's not necessarily a defect

`_Thread_local` is a storage duration added to the C programming language with the release of C11, and you're right, it is not explicitly associated with the `threads.h` library header file. It acts like a `static` variable that is only visible to one thread, so that each thread can have their own local static-like variables.

A conforming C11 compiler that defines `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` to 1 need not include or support the functions or types in `threads.h` but must still support the duration specifier `_Thread_local`. This allows programmers writing multi-threaded programs in C using non-standard threading libraries such as the POSIX standard `pthread.h` to declare static-like variables local to a specific thread in their programs, even if `threads.h` is not supported in said compiler.

As you pointed out there's a proposal to add it to the list of things that need not be included when `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` is defined as 1, but I imagine there will be debate on both sides as to its utility for older longer-established threading libraries, even when the C-standard `threads.h` library is not yet supported.

Comment: Re: "`__STDC_NO_THREADS__` to 1 need not include or support the functions or types declared in `threads.h` or `stdatomic.h`": the definition of `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` says nothing about `stdatomic.h`.

Comment: It actually does. C11 standard section 6.10.8.3 says the macro is “ intended to indicate that the implementation does not support atomic types (including the _Atomic type qualifier and the <stdatomic.h> header) or the <threads.h> header.”

Comment: You're probably looking at Committee Draft. Here is the quote from the C11, Third edition 2011-12-15: "`__STDC_NO_THREADS__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the implementation does not support the `<threads.h>` header."

Comment: Alright. You got me

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that currently `_Thread_local` is independent from `__STDC_NO_THREADS__`.

Yes.

> Consequence: even if an implementation defines **STDC_NO_THREADS** to 1, then it still needs to support (at least to accept) _Thread_local.

Yes.

> I guess that it is a defect. Is that correct?

It is not a defect.  There is nothing inconsistent there, and no particular problem for a C implementation that does not support *multi*threading to recognize and accept the `_Thread_local` storage class specifier.  In such an implementation, there is no meaningful distinction between thread storage duration and static storage duration, because the single thread of each program has the same lifetime as the program itself.  `_Thread_local` places very little extra burden on developers or purveyors of such implementations.

That there is a proposal to make support of the `_Thread_local` storage class specifier optional in C2X means very little, and I do hope that proposal is not accepted.  We do not need more optional features in C than we already have, especially not optional keywords or syntactic constructs,
and `_Thread_local` does no harm to implementations that don't support threads.

Comment: Re: "optional keywords": to remind: support of `_Atomic` depends on value of `__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__`.

Comment: Yes, @pmor.  So what?  I repeat: "We do not need more optional features in C than we already have, especially not optional keywords or syntactic constructs."