# Are "thread storage duration" and "thread local storage duration" the synonyms?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, thread-local-storage, storage-duration

C11, 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects, 4 (emphasis added):

> An object whose identifier is declared with the storage-class specifier `_Thread_local` has **thread storage duration**.

C11, 7.5 Errors <errno.h>, 2 (emphasis added):

> `errno` which expands to a modifiable lvalue 201) that has type `int` and **thread local storage
> duration**

Are "thread storage duration" and "thread local storage duration" the synonyms?

---

Extra note: currently the support of `_Thread_local` is independent of `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` while it is (probably) [expected to be dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71770606/1778275).

Comment: Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289634/thread-local-storage-class-specifier-in-c. As far as I understood it's the same thing.

Comment: They are the same. The term is used to specify a variable that has its storage **local** to the thread that declare it. The variable **`errno`** is a classic example, it holds the error code of last library call of the executing thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are "thread storage duration" and "thread local storage duration" the synonyms?

That's the only plausible interpretation I see, yes.  The definition of storage duration in paragraph 6.2.4/1 of the spec does not include a "thread local storage duration":

> There are four storage durations: static, thread, automatic, and allocated.

However, thread storage duration is the storage duration of identifiers declared with the `_Thread_local` storage class specifier, and it is fairly common in general discussion to describe the objects associated with such identifiers as "thread local".  I take the appearance of "thread local storage duration" in in section 7.5 -- which is the only appearance of that term in the spec -- to constitute an editorial error, but I don't think the intended meaning is in doubt.  This is reinforced by the spec's remarks that

> The value of errno in the initial thread is zero at program startup (the initial value of errno in other threads is an indeterminate value)

(C11 7.5/3).

That `errno` may have different values in different threads can be explained in only two ways:

1. `errno` has thread storage duration, OR
2. this is a special, unique characteristic of `errno`, provided by some means other than it having thread storage duration.

I find explanation (2) altogether implausible in light of the spec overall.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They are the same thing.

The specification for the C11 library file `errno.h` is telling you that `errno` shall behave as if declared as:

```
_Thread_local int errno;
```

and the storage duration specification is telling you what `_Thread_local` means

Comment: FYI: Per C11, 7.5/2 the `errno` is a **macro** "which expands to a **modifiable lvalue** 201) that has type `int` and thread local storage duration, the value of which is set to a positive error number by several library functions". And per footnote 201: "The macro `errno` need not be the identifier of an object".